# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code =EXC_1386,INVOP,subcode=0x0) error

Tags: ios, swift, crash, parse-platform, exc-bad-instruction

When I try to pull the content subclass of my NewsPages Class from my Parse.com account, the app crashes and the log gives me the : `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code =EXC_1386,INVOP,subcode=0x0) error`.

Please Help Me fix this.

Here is the Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var teamNewsTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {



        var query = PFQuery(className:"NewsPages")
        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("KerL5Xf0Bx") {
            (NewsPages: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let content = NewsPages["content"] as String

                self.teamNewsTextView.text = content

            } else {
                NSLog("%@", error)
            }
        }



}}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 if error == nil {

if let content = NewsPages["content"] as? String
{
  self.teamNewsTextView.text = content

}
} 
else {
    NSLog("%@", error)
}
```

Comment: does it reflects any line?

Comment: I don't think so but is there a way to make sure?

Comment: Enable Zombie objects as here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html

Then re run your application. And let me know what appers in consol